# Setup Team Foundation Server in VMWare

Tags: vmware, windows-server-2008, iis

Has anyone tried running TFS in a VMWare VM and Visual Studio on the host machine? Need some help with network settings, everything seems fine except that the host doesn't see the TFS VM in its network.

I guess this is a more generic question not just for TFS. How can the host machine access a network service on the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to make sure the VM has a 'bridged' network instead of using NAT. This way the VM will appear as another computer on the same network.

I run TFS inside a 2008R2 VM in VMware ESXi (you don't specify what product you're using so I'm assuming VMware Workstation) on a remote machine without any issues using bridged networking.